# How to spy on an object not created in the test code with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In the code I'm trying to test I have the following:

```
const redisClient = redis.createClient({ url: `redis://${process.env.REDIS_ADDRESS}:${process.env.REDIS_PORT}` })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        logging.error(`Redis Client Error ${utils.getErrorJson(err)}`)
    });
```

The test function looks like this:

```
it('should log error when creating redit client fails', async () => {
        redis.createClient = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            throw new Error('test error');
        });

        jest.spyOn(redisClient, 'on');
    });
```

Is there any way to spy on the 'on' function in the SUT code so I can verify it was called? Obviously the restClient object is not declared in a scope that the test code can see. So is there some

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question as your solution looks correct to me. Are you expecting the unit test to apply to the real redis client during the program's runtime rather than during the running of unit tests? (if that happens to be the case, runtime assertions will help with this)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few concerns with your approach.

First, the `redis.createClient` method is calling an underlying function (see their [code](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/dbf8f59a47573e6a1c75b78e566af8c493015d5d/index.ts#L41-L55)) that returns an object singleton to interact with redis.

An example of this could look something like this...

```
class FakeRedisClient {
  constructor(args) {
    this.onEventHandlers = {};
    // init redis with args
  }

  on(type, fun) {
    if (!this.onEventHandlers[type]) {
      this.onEventHandlers[type] = [];
    }
    
    this.onEventHandlers[type].push(fun);

    return this;
  }
  
  connect() {
    // do connection
    const error = {} // some error
    if (error) {
      const handlers = this.onEventHandlers['error'] ?? [];
      handlers.forEach((fun) => fun(error))
    }
    
  }
}

const redis = {
  createClient: (args) => new FakeRedisClient(args)
}
```

But in your test code your are trying to override `redis.createClient` thus stripping away the `on` handling logic, to where `redisClient.on` would **never** be called. Testing singletons such as this is a bit tricky.

If you did want to test this, you could mock the implementation of the `redis.redisClient` import but you'd need to handle the on logic yourself, similar to the `FakeRedisClient` above.

```
jest.mock('redis', () => ({
  createClient: (args) => new FakeRedisClient(args),
}));
```

You could also skip the mock and get the `redisClient` to fail by passing bad arguments, but this could be tricky.

In the end you are on the fine line of testing that the redis client does what it should, instead of testing your own code. Meaning, redis has it's own unit tests to ensure `on` is called appropriately.

I would suggest you abstract the error handling logic into a function that you can test on its own, then pass that to the `redisClient`.

```
const handleRedisError = (err) => {
  logging.error(`Redis Client Error ${utils.getErrorJson(err)}`)
}
const redisClient = redis.createClient({ url: `redis://${process.env.REDIS_ADDRESS}:${process.env.REDIS_PORT}` })
    .on('error', handleRedisError);
```

Comment: Thank you for your highly detailed answer. It makes sense. You're right though about testing redis' logic instead of trusting it works. In all honesty my main motivation for trying this out was to increase my code coverage so there would be fewer uncovered lines in the coverage report. Might be more work than it's worth to really get this to work. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah I still find it difficult to find the right balance. In this case you could test it separately but then someone could easily remove the `.on('error', fun)` call and break things that are not being tested. Mocks have their place even though many people may disagree. But at the end of the day unit tests provide some safety but also hinder refactoring down the road. Testing this type of code at a higher level, eases this pain but can be harder to implement/mock/etc. Also many libraries use `/* istanbul ignore next */` for these exact cases to *improve* coverage.